# text over image not responsive in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an image, over which I am putting some heading on the right and left side of the image like below

```
<div class="container-fluid no-padding">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="col-sm-3 text-center image-overlapping">
       <h1>Hello Suarj</h1>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam omnis, ipsum eveniet minus amet. 
      </div>
       <img src="http://oi65.tinypic.com/15oi0w9.jpg" class="ls-bg" alt="Slide background" style="width:100%; height:auto;">
       <div class="col-sm-3 text-center image-overlapping right">
        <h1>Hello Suarj</h1>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam omnis, ipsum eveniet minus amet.
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This works well for me, but it is not responsive for the mobile. How do I go about it.

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/65upzvk6/5/) the fiddle for the same.

Comment: Where's the heading?

Comment: there is no text. You could take a look into media querys. they can help you when you have problems with mobile views etc

Comment: Apologies. Updated the question now..

Comment: Try to put all content in separate `div` element ?? using `bootstrap column property`.

Comment: that's what I want to know how...

Comment: If I get you correctly, you can get desired result by adding xs, md and lg values along with `col-sm-3`.

Comment: Enclose the <img> in a div.col-sm-3 and remove the position absolute and right css

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/65upzvk6/18/

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid no-padding">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2 text-center image-overlapping">
          <h1>Hello Suarj</h1>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam omnis, ipsum eveniet minus amet. Provident, qui nisi voluptatum laboriosam ut vitae eaque nesciunt cumque omnis! Porro esse culpa fugiat molestias ab! Odit, quibusdam sunt consectetur optio ea velit accusamus voluptatem.
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-8">
          <img src="http://oi65.tinypic.com/15oi0w9.jpg" class="ls-bg" alt="Slide background" style="width:100%; height:auto;" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2 text-center image-overlapping">
          <h1>Hello Suarj</h1>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam omnis, ipsum eveniet minus amet. Provident, qui nisi voluptatum laboriosam ut vitae eaque nesciunt cumque omnis! Porro esse culpa fugiat molestias ab! Odit, quibusdam sunt consectetur optio ea velit accusamus voluptatem.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is one more way to skip position absolute.

Comment: Looks nice. The font size though is looking very small of the text below the heading.. How can we change that?

Answer (score 0):

So I added this media-query

```
 @media (max-width: 480px){
   .image-overlapping {position: relative; top : 0 !important;}
 }
```

And added `col-xs-12` to the div which has my heading.

It works for me. Thanks for help.

Comment: even though I suggested using `media querys you` should take a look at Shiladitya solution (or at least thank him), his solution seems more clear and is the better one ;)